Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect
I've followed the instructions in recent versions of CiviCRM and added this line to civicrm.settings.php:
define('CIVICRM_SMARTY3_AUTOLOAD_PATH',
'/home/<username>/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/autoload.php');

It seemed to be running fine, so I ran the latest update and this happened:
$ cv upgrade:db
PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/gdpr.civix.php on line 100
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/gdpr.civix.php on line 100
PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.shoreditch-1.0.0-beta.12/shoreditch.civix.php on line 100
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.shoreditch-1.0.0-beta.12/shoreditch.civix.php on line 100
PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/easycopy/easycopy.civix.php on line 100
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/easycopy/easycopy.civix.php on line 100
Found CiviCRM database version 5.71.1.
Found CiviCRM code version 5.72.1.
Checking pre-upgrade messages...
(No messages)
Dropping SQL triggers...
Preparing upgrade...
Executing upgrade...
...............Error: Call to a member function getOutputByName() on null in Civi\DataProcessor\Output\UIOutputHelper::buildNavigationMenuItems() (line 93 of /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/dataprocessor/Civi/DataProcessor/Output/UIOutputHelper.php).

Assuming the update had failed, I commented the Smarty update lines out and ran it again, but cv said I was already running 5.72.1. So I uncommented it again and everything still seemed fine.
But I've just noticed that I'm getting most of the same errors every time cron runs:
PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/gdpr.civix.php on line 100
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/gdpr.civix.php on line 100
PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.shoreditch-1.0.0-beta.12/shoreditch.civix.php on line 100
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.shoreditch-1.0.0-beta.12/shoreditch.civix.php on line 100
PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/easycopy/easycopy.civix.php on line 100
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property CRM_Core_Smarty::$template_dir has no effect in /home/<username>/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/easycopy/easycopy.civix.php on line 100

Have I done something wrong, or do I just need to wait until those extensions get updates?

I would remove the AUTOLOAD line from civicrm.settings.php until those extensions have updates available. They'll need to re-run civix upgrade and put out a release.
But the Error: Call to a member function getOutputByName() in the dataprocessor extension is something unrelated to smarty. But it might be something temporary while cache was being cleared and if you're not seeing that error anymore it's probably ok.
